# Struts2 JQuery grid - empty grid message

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, grid

I'm using Struts2 JQuery grids and it works fine.

Here is an example of grid:

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable"
        caption="Customer Examples"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="10,15,20"
        rowNum="15"
        rownumbers="true"
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit" title="Credit Limit" formatter="currency" sortable="false"/>
    </sjg:grid>
```

I would like to display a specific message when the grid is empty instead of showing an empty grid. I know that this can be done by encapsulating the whole grid in a `s:if` statement but I would like to avoid retrieving information twice if the grid has contents (one for the if statement, then a second time for the grid itself).

Is there an option to do the following "isEmpty" message?

```
<sjg:grid
        id="gridtable"
        ifEmpty="No data to display!"
```

Or some other mechanism like that where I can display  a button to create a new entry?

Comment: Alternatively, is there an option to retrieve the number of objects returned by the URL "jsontable" in a if statement? Something like `<s:if test="remoteurl.size>0">` ? That would not be the best solution, but at least a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the event *onCompleteTopics* and some script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.subscribe('completegrid', function(event, data) {
        var records = $('#gridtable').getGridParam('records');
            if(records < 1) {
                $('#gridcontainer').html('<span>none</span>');
            }
});
</script>

<sjg:grid
        ...
        onCompleteTopics ="completegrid"
        ...
>
```

See reference on http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Topics

Comment: Seems like a promising idea, I'll have to try. Do you have any idea on how to make that generic enough, so I can reuse the same script for multiple grids on the same page? Something like `onCompleteTopics ="completegrid(gridtableId)"` ?

Comment: Maybe even the gridcontainer (I assume is a separate div?) could be simplified?

Comment: yeah, `gridcontainer` it's suppossed to be a div for each grid.
You can use `<sjg:grid cssClass="grids"` and select all the grids in the script by adding something like:

`$.subscribe('completegrid', function(event, data) {
        $(".grids").each(function(idx,data){
            var records = $(this).getGridParam('records');
            if(records < 1) {
                $(this).parent('div')html('<span>none</span>');
            }
        });

});`

please check the jquery selector for `$(this).parent` i can't remember right now if it is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Nickmancol, I posted another question you might be able to help me with if you are in the mood ;-)